# Order of growth of recurrence $4T(n/4) + n\log n^3$

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics

I'm trying to figure out the order of growth of the recurrence as follows, assuming $T(1) = 1$:

\begin{align*}
4T(n/4) + n \log n^3 & = 4T(n/4) + 3n \log n\\
&=4^kT(n/4^k) + \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} (3/4^j) n \log (n/4^j)
\end{align*}

Where the logs are base $4$.

Letting $k = \log_4 n$:

$$
=nT(1) + \sum_{j=0}^{\log_4 n-1} (3/4^j) n \log (n/4^j)
$$

Now I guess I took the easy way out and write:

\begin{align*}
&= n + \sum_{j=0}^{\log_4 n-1} (3/4^j) n \log (n/4^j) \\
&\le n + \sum_{j=0}^{\log_4 n-1} 3 n \log (n) \\ 
&= n + \log n [3 n \log (n)] \\
&= n + 3n\log^2n \\ 
&= O(n \log^2 n)
\end{align*}

but I am wondering if this bound can be made tighter, or if there is a good way of telling when such comparisons can be made.

**update**
If I don't make that assumption and instead write:

\begin{align*}
n + \sum_{j=0}^{\log_4 n-1} (3/4^j) n \log (n/4^j) &= n + 3n \bigg [ \log n \sum_{j=0}^{\log_4 n-1} \frac{1}{4^j}  - \log 4\sum_{j=0}^{\log_4 n-1}\frac{j}{4^j} \bigg ]  \\
& = n + 3n [ \log n O(n) - \log 4 O(\log n)]\\
&= O(n \log n)
\end{align*}

Comment: You are correct. The recurrence is of the form $T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n)$ where $$f(n)\in\Theta\left(n^{\log_ba}\log n\right),$$ and hence by the master theorem, $$T(n)\in\Theta (n\log^2 n). $$

Comment: @Math1000 is this case covered by the MT? maybe im seeing a restricted version